# Character %20 escaping when using Exec Command in .wixproj file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

Git command is used in BeforeBuild section of a WiX project. URL used contains character %20, that is replaced by space during build process.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command='git clone "https://example.url.com/My%20Project/Repo"' />
```

Cloning works fine when used on command line, but not when used in WiX project, because a space in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem eventually. Normally char % would be used to escape another % char and it will also work in this case, but all characters must be URL encoded when using Command in WiX project.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command='git clone "https://example.url.com/My%25%25%32%30Project/Repo"' />
```